# Possible to "ping" url:port? (OS X-GeekTool)

Tags: port-forwarding, ip, ping, geektool

I'm trying to use GeekTool (Mac pref pane... basically just embeds output of a shell command/script on the desktop... http://lifehacker.com/#!244026/geek-to-live--monitor-your-mac-and-more-with-geektool) to monitor a a remote machines/server, and I'm having some trouble determining how best to check if a machine is up/down.

I'm using no-ip as a free dns re-direct... but this only helps me with the public IP of the router. The machine I want is behind the router and thus isn't able to be "ping"ed directly.

I have port forwarding set up for port 8080 which leads to the machine I want. Is there a way to essentially ping through port 8080 to see if the machine is up and running? I tried telnet, but this apparently doesn't work (as far as output) in GeekTool. I'm running a website at 8080, so I guess I just want to know if/when it goes down.

Thanks in advance... if I can provide more clarification let me know.

(figured out my problem... see below)

Comment: `ping` is an ICMP protocol, whereas ports are TCP and UDP concepts. All 3 are distinct protocols on top of IP. That means an IP packet containing TCP cannot contain ICMP and vice versa. It also means the TCP header (with the port) is not present in an ICMP ping packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telnet gets the job done, but I'm unable to integrate that with GeekTool. **I ended up doing a mysqladmin ping to the remote machine**. The website has a db backend, so this (more-or-less) returns the info I'm looking for. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 42):

To check a specific port, you can use telnet:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
```

(The port follows the IP / hostname with a space, not a colon.)

If you get an immediate error, then the port is not available. If telnet hangs, then you have successfully connected to the port. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill telnet, then.

This may or may not help with the port forwarding issue, though. It just gets you to that IP and port.

Comment: This would get the job done... but it doesn't work with GeekTool :/. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You might need to run `brew install telnet` to install telnet.

Comment: Keep in mind this only works for TCP ports. For UDP ports use netcat : `nc -u <host> <port>`

Answer (score 10):

Theres is [hping](http://www.hping.org) utility that allows you to ping TCP ports. This is also available via homebrew (brew install hping).

[backdrift.org](http://backdrift.org/tcp-ping-ping-tcp-port) gives a simple instructions on how to use hping for this purpose

```
$ hping -S -p 80 google.com
HPING google.com (eth0 66.249.92.104): S set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
len=44 ip=66.249.92.104 ttl=47 id=10442 sport=80 flags=SA seq=0 win=5720 rtt=97.7 ms
len=44 ip=66.249.92.104 ttl=47 id=40838 sport=80 flags=SA seq=1 win=5720 rtt=97.7 ms
len=44 ip=66.249.92.104 ttl=47 id=64607 sport=80 flags=SA seq=2 win=5720 rtt=97.7 ms
len=44 ip=66.249.92.104 ttl=47 id=10443 sport=80 flags=SA seq=3 win=5720 rtt=97.7 ms
^C
--- google.com hping statistic ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 97.7/97.7/97.7 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wget`, `curl` etc. to check that the website is responding.

Comment: This only can check a web service port.

Comment: @244boy The question said "I'm running a website at 8080", so I thought it was a reasonable way to check.